# Iphone login application

Tags: iphone, http, ios4

I'm new in world of iphone programming. I try to make simple login application. My goal is to have 2 different view controllers. When app start login screen should appear. This screen contains two Text fields and one button(login). I want when user press login button to send his username and password to remote server through http and if they are legal to load tab bar controller with two bars. In first bar user should see his id and in second to see his mail. Is it possible this and can you give some direction?

Best regards,
Nikolay

Comment: Is it possible this and can you give some direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

After entering the account details user will press the login button. On that event you can send the account details to the remote server using NSURLConnection. After authenticating details in the server. Server should send a response with the status of sucess/failure in an XML. You can catch the response and parse the message using a XML parser example:NSXMLParser. If the message is success then call the method to show the TabController. If message is failure then show some alert.

You will be in need of some class like [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for server communication. And [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for parsing data. You can check sample apps of this classes for better understanding and their implementation. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

I Guess the answer you want is how to lad the views in a odered way... if so, you must first load the tabbar. on the viewDidload from your first view controller, load the login view controller in a modal way, using delegate to return to the main view after the login...

loading a view controller modally:

```
[self PresentModalViewController:yourController];
```